# Picasso sample error/doesn't compile

Tags: java, android, image, picasso

I downloaded the Picasso image cache library and tried to get the sample code to work. I set up an Android project from the existing code, included the picasso-2.2.0.jar and android-support-v4.jar

However, when I tried to compile and run it, it says there are errors in the PicassoSampleAdapter and SampleWidgetProvider files.

This is the line in question:

```
picasso.load(Data.URLS[new Random().nextInt(Data.URLS.length)]) //
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //
    .error(R.drawable.error) //
    .transform(new GrayscaleTransformation(picasso)) //
    .into(updateViews, R.id.image, appWidgetIds);
```

And this is the error:

```
The method into(ImageView, Callback) in the type RequestCreator is not applicable for the arguments (RemoteViews, int, int[])
```

I checked the documentation on the picasso website and indeed, into takes those two parameters. It seems inconceivable to me that there'd be an error like this on such a great library, so I'm thinking it must be something I'm not doing right when setting this up? The other files do not have errors in them, so I believe I've set things up right.

Can anyone help? Do you have the same error when you try to set up the sample project and run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample on `master` is for the code on `master`. That is, it only works with the Picasso library that also exists on `master` (2.3.0-SNAPSHOT). The `RemoteView` variant of the `into()` API hasn't been released yet.

If you are using version 2.2.0, you need to use the sample from version 2.2.0 which can be found here: https://github.com/square/picasso/tree/picasso-parent-2.2.0/picasso-sample (note the matching tag in the URL).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.java

into method takes one or two parameters. Pass your imageView instance there.

Comment: i know. this code snippet is from the sample on github. I was afraid to assume that the sample code from square is wrong, but it seems like this might be the case?

Comment: look specifically at https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso-sample/src/main/java/com/example/picasso/SampleWidgetProvider.java

Comment: can you place your whole code ? Or you are using the same code as in example ?

Comment: im only using the sample code from the link. Did not type any other code

Answer (score 0):

Error is at line where you are calling `.into(updateViews, R.id.image, appWidgetIds);` It has three variants as mentioned here http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/index.html. You can change it to `.into(updateViews)` and it should work. Assuming `updateViews` is the `ImageView` you want to load the final image into.